# In magento 2, how to edit the uploaded image field

Tags: magento2, database, image-upload, custom-field

In magento 2, how to edit the uploaded image field

I follow this blog https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-ui-component-image-upload/

[image]

> ui-component

```
<field name="promo_image">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">specialpromotion</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Bg_SpecialPromotion/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path=bg_specialpromotion/index/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
   </field>
```

> Bg\SpecialPromotion\etc\di.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="Bg\SpecialPromotion\ImageUpload" type="Bg\SpecialPromotion\Model\ImageUploader">
    <arguments>
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">test/tmp</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">test</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Bg\SpecialPromotion\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Upload">
    <arguments>
            <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Bg\SpecialPromotion\ImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Bg\SpecialPromotion\Model\SalesRule\DataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Bg\SpecialPromotion\ImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Bg\SpecialPromotion\Observer\SaveImage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Bg\SpecialPromotion\ImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

> Bg\SpecialPromotion\Observer\SaveImage

```
 <?php
namespace Bg\SpecialPromotion\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class SaveImage implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
     // $data = $observer->getRequest()->getPostValue();
      $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
       $img_name = $request->getPostValue('promo_image');

       if(!empty( $img_name ))
       {
         if(!is_array($img_name ))
         {
            $img = $img_name;  
         }
         else
         {
           $img = $img_name[0]['name']; 
         }
        // $this->imageUploader = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Bg\SpecialPromotion\ImageUpload');
        // $this->imageUploader->moveFileFromTmp($img);
       }
       else  
       {
           $img =  NULL;
       }   
      $request->setPostValue('promo_image',$img);
    }  
}
```

**after save the uploaded image and edit the save image field not appear in admin**

[image]

> Bg\SpecialPromotion\Model\SalesRul\DataProvider.php

```
namespace Bg\SpecialPromotion\Model\SalesRule;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{

    protected $salesRuleFactory;
    public function __construct(

    \Bg\SpecialPromotion\Model\ResourceModel\SalesRule\CollectionFactory $salesRuleFactory, 

    )
    {

    $this->collection = $salesRuleFactory;

    }
    public function getData()
    {

        $items = $this->collection->getItems();

        //Replace icon with fileuploader field name
        foreach ($items as $model) {
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
            if ($model->getPromoImage()) {
                $m['promo_image'][0]['name'] = $model->getPromoImage();
                $m['promo_image'][0]['url'] = $this->getMediaUrl().$model->getPromoImage();
                $fullData = $this->loadedData;
                $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = array_merge($fullData[$model->getId()], $m);
            }
        }

        return $this->loadedData;
    }

    public function getMediaUrl()
    {
        $mediaUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'test/tmp/';
        return $mediaUrl;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219924/save-cart-price-rule-custom-fields-in-database

Comment: add your custom field code

Comment: I  m using this blog to done image upload https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-ui-component-image-upload/

Comment: @divyasekar Can you please upload your data provider class file?

Comment: I have update a post @Rohan

Comment: Did you override this model with core or this model call in cart rule edit page?

Comment: this model call  in cart rule edit page

Comment: Did you checked that your model call perfect in cart rule edit page?

Comment: image can save into the model data

Comment: this may help you => https://inchoo.net/magento-2/file-upload-in-magento-2-store-configuration/

Answer (score 2):

On Step 5: Controller Save Image. There is a line which tell the uploader move the image uploaded from `baseTmpPath` : `test/tmp` to `basePath` : `test`

```
$this->imageUploader->moveFileFromTmp($data['image']);
```

So basically on your `Bg\SpecialPromotion\Model\SalesRul\DataProvider.php` the function to get the media url should be

```
public function getMediaUrl()
    {
        $mediaUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'test/';
        return $mediaUrl;
    }
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `value.map` usually, come from `di.xml`, please ensure you have created your own virtual type and inject it into every file you use `ImageUploader`.

For e.g

> etc\di.xml

```
<!-- CMS Image Uploader -->
<virtualType name="Bg\SpecialPromotion\ThumbnailImageUpload" type="Bg\SpecialPromotion\Model\ImageUploader">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">sales/tmp/promo</argument>
        <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">sales/promo</argument>
        <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
            <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
            <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
            <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">svg</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Bg\SpecialPromotion\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Upload">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Bg\SpecialPromotion\ThumbnailImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Bg\SpecialPromotion\Plugin\Model\Page\DataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Bg\SpecialPromotion\ThumbnailImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Bg\SpecialPromotion\Observer\SalesRulePrepareSave">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Bg\SpecialPromotion\ThumbnailImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i  corrected my di.xml  file  after i upload and save a image i will get a  error like this **Notice: Undefined variable: data in D:\wamp64\www\m2\magento\vendor\magento\module-sales-rule\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Save.php on line 102**

Comment: What is line 102 and how 'data' looks like? @divyasekar

Comment: here the screen shot is https://prnt.sc/oun2ty

Comment: That line does not look line a core Magento code. It says undefined variable because $data defined inside try block. Remove that line and try again.

Comment: i will remove the $data inside a block again its  reflect a same error

Comment: i corrected my di.xml file  but i will  get a https://prnt.sc/ow4cgp

Comment: Check the media permissions once. Could be an issue that due to wrong permissions, it is not coming on edit page. Just a suggestion

Comment: how to check the media permission